# Equivalent for $R_n=\sum_{p=n+1}^{+\infty}\frac{\sqrt{p}}{p!}$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

I'm asked, as $n$ tends to $+\infty$, to find an equivalent form for $$ R_n=\sum_{p=n+1}^{+\infty}\frac{\sqrt{p}}{p!}.$$   I've just found that $$0\leq R_n \leq \sum_{p=n+1}^{+\infty}\frac{1}{(p-1)!}=e-\sum_{p=0}^{n}\frac{1}{p!}.$$ I'm having problems estimating the last sum. Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We have

$$R_n=\sum_{p=n+1}\frac{\sqrt p}{p!}=\sum_{p=n}^\infty\frac1{p!\sqrt{p+1}}=\frac1{n!\sqrt{n+1}}+\underbrace{\sum_{p=n+1}^\infty\frac1{p!\sqrt{p+1}}}_{=R'_n}$$
and

$$R'_n\le\frac1{\sqrt{n+2}}\sum_{p=n+1}^\infty\frac1{p!}\le \frac1{(n+1)!\sqrt{n+2}}\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac1{2^k}$$
so we see that

$$R_n=\frac1{n!\sqrt n}+o\left(\frac1{n!\sqrt n}\right)$$
hence we conclude
$$R_n\sim_\infty\frac1{n!\sqrt n}$$

Comment: Excellent! Thank you very much!

Comment: You're welcome.

Answer (score 2):

The Stirling's inequality gives:
$$ n! \geq n^n e^{-n}\sqrt{2\pi n} $$
hence:
$$\frac{\sqrt{p}}{p!}\leq \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\left(\frac{e}{p}\right)^p $$
and:
$$\sum_{p>n}\frac{\sqrt{p}}{p!}\leq\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\sum_{p>n}\left(\frac{e}{n}\right)^p \leq \frac{\left(\frac{e}{n}\right)^n}{\sqrt{2\pi}\left(1-\frac{e}{n}\right)}.$$

Comment: Thank you for your answer! +1.